# aqquire localhost.json from azufunction (powershell commands install failed and I found no az-command for cmd.exe) Any Solutions?

Tags: powershell, command-line, azure-functions

I installed last year the powershell az core tools with big problems but got it working.

I used this 2 Commands to get the local.settings.json iwth actual values:

```
Connect-AzAccount -Tenant 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' -SubscriptionId 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'

func azure functionapp fetch-app-settings '<function-name>' --output-file local.settings.json
```

On installing the powershell core tools we spend a few hours and failed , so i tried to find similar command für standard command line (CMD.exe) but I found no similar command that worked so.

I found only this:

```
az login --tenant "xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

this sets the correct tenant and this worked.

I found additionally thsis commad to set the subscription but i got no response:

```
# change the active subscription using the subscription ID
az account set --subscription "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

And I could request the config setting on screen with that command:

```
az functionapp config appsettings list --name MyFunctionApp --resource-group MyResourceGroup
```

But i found no way to create with the az command the local.setings.json and the file is in wrong  format so piping it in a file will not work too.

```
[
...
  {
    "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
    "slotSetting": false,
    "value": "dotnet"
  },
...
]
```

Can anyone help me to get the file local.settings.json with actual config values with the az commands from standard windows shell.

Answer (score 0):

- Generally, `local.settings.json` file is ignored while publishing to Azure Function App as it is specified in the `.gitignore` file:

[image]

- While publishing/deploying the function app, make sure to publish with the [setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-core-tools-reference?tabs=v2#func-azure-functionapp-publish) `--publish-local-settings -i`.

Syntax:

`func azure functionapp publish <FunctionAppName> --publish-local-settings -i`

- Then, all the local.settings.json config values can be published and the values using the PowerShell cmdlet will be displayed:

```
Get-AzFunctionAppSetting -Name FunctionAppName -ResourceGroupName RGName | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File "local.settings.json"
```

- OR use the same `Az` cmdlet to get the correct format of config settings defined in `local.settings.json` that are published to Azure function app.

[image]

> to get the file local.settings.json with actual config values

**Using az command** for saving the published `local.settings.json` config values in a file:

```
az functionapp config appsettings list --name MyFunctionApp --resource-group MyResourceGroup --output json > local.settings.json
```

[image]

Comment: most stuff you answer i wrote  in the question. I know and use the powershell commandlets. But commandlets don't work an a collegues PC and  install fails. and the az functionapp config appsettings list.. generally deliveres json otput not the special format  for the local.settings.json. the parameter --output json has no influence.

Comment: I have shown the syntax of all cmdlets for fetching the `local.settings.json` config values and saving in a file where all these cmdlets worked for me! If these are not working in your colleagues PC, please provide the error message or screenshots

Comment: On missing timewe  cancelled installation az powershell commandlets  and i searched for an equivalent for the az command for windows command shell( cmd.exe) no powershell commandlets.  **The only the question was:**
_Is there to a way get only with Az command the an working local.settings.json file with actual configuration?_